# Applications/Motivations of matrix decomposition techniques

Tags: matrices, block-matrices, svd

Matrix decomposition is one area of matrices that has always intrigued me. Every time I open a matrix book, I can interestingly follow it till Eigen values and Eigen vectors because they are well motivated.

However, I am not able to understand the motivation of matrix decomposition techniques.
I am just revising on Matrices before I start learning linear and non linear optimization methods for machine learning.

It would be great if people here could motivate the need and benefits of matrix decomposition techniques like LU, QR, Cholesky, SVD etc. Also, any interpretations of matrix decomposition techniques (if any) would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: The techniques you ask about are used for many purposes, including the obvious one: solve a linear system efficiently.  As a general point consider that factoring a matrix into two pieces that are easy to solve may well be more efficient than inverting the matrix.

Comment: Its a nice question and falls in my area of "expertise". I am a bit occupied at the moment, if no one replies in the next 12 hours, I will.

Comment: What would you rather compute, powers of the LHS or powers of the RHS of the equality below?
$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2\\0 & 3 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\0& 3 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 &-1\\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Well, I am still confused. 

Is everyone implying here that Matrix decomposition techniques were primarily invented to overcome computational limitations. In that sense it is more of an strategy to improve the speed or accuracy of other real algorithms.

I was under the assumption that Matrix decomposition also provides additional insights into the properties of the matrix in itself; In way I was hoping for Matrix decomposition to be more of a tool for a Mathematician deriving proofs rather than to an engineer who needs to implement a particular numeric algorithm

Answer (score 6):

Eigenvalues and eigenvectors lead naturally to the spectral theorem, diagonalization of matrices, and Jordan normal form. This is all indeed very elegant and nice but there are several problems.

First, there is the practical one. How do you actually solve a large system of linear equations on a computer and how do you actually diagonalize a large matrix (that theory tells you is diagonalizable) on a computer. These are very difficult problems since there is a huge gap between the theoretical results and actual computations. That gap is caused of course by rounding errors on a computer. Loads of books are written on the subject as, needless to say, it's of immense importance. Many factorizations of matrices (e.g., LU and QR) are meant to address such issues. To make computations more robust and more efficient.

As for motivating SVD, nothing can be easier. Consider the following questions regarding a linear transformation $T:V\to W$ where $V,W$ are inner product spaces (say over $\mathbb R$) not necessarily of the same dimension (so there is no point of speaking of eigenvalues or Jordan form or any of that):

1) What is the shape of the image under $T$ of the unit sphere in $V$.

2) If $T$ is not invertible, how do you invert it in the best way you can.

3) How do you solve $Tx=b$ when no solution exists.

4) How do you replace $T$ by another transformation of smaller rank (a useful question for data analysis and compression).

the list goes on, but the answer to all of these questions is:SVD.

Comment: Are you saying that the purpose of SVD is to approximate?

Comment: no @ajay, it has other uses too.

Answer (score 0):

It generally depends on what you are trying to achieve via matrix decomposition.

For example, my primary area (MIMO detection) uses it on solving inversions of matrix (as it will reduce complexity in hardware implementation). Take LU, for instance, $L$ is a lower-triangular matrix, which can be invested in $1/6*O(N^3)$, $U$, and vice versa, shares the same quality. However, when one does matrix inversion directly, it will take $2*O(N^3)$.